# Manipulating a variable also affects the variable that was used to initialized it

Tags: typescript

So I have this code

```
let dataToExport: any[] = this.employees;
dataToExport.forEach(function(v){delete v.profPic});
```

The this.employees variable is an array of objects. I want to a remove certain attribute, profPic, of each object in that array without changing anything on the this.employees variable that's why I made another variable which is dataToExport and initialized it with this.employees. The problem is after executing these commands I found out that the this.employees also changed even though I only used the dataToExport to manipulate the array. I found this out by using console log. Is there something wrong in my code? What should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you can guarantee there are only objects in that array - `let dataToExport: any[] = this.employees.map(v => Object.assign({}, v))`

Comment: Yeah there are  only objects in this array. It worked thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing with your code. It's because when you do a simple assignment, you're just getting a reference to the original variable. To fix it, use something like lodash and use _.clone